# Python list comprehension and lowercase

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has mixed case values.  I do NOT want to change everything to lowercase but what I want to do is use dictionary comprehension to get the values out but have those values be lowercase.

```
EmployeeIDs = [Employee.get('externalEmployeeId', '') for Employee in activeEmployees]
```

At the moment this is returning mixed case in the EmployeeIDs result.  I know I can go to a more traditional for loop - but I am curious if I can make this convert to lowercase, also.  I can't just put .lower() after the paren because it can return None which does not support lowercase.  And I could put ' ' instead of '' in this specific case but it seems to me I should be able to put some kind of expression here instead of just the .get?

Comment: Can you add an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem?

Comment: That's a list comprehension, not a dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Doesn't `Employee.get('externalEmployeeId', '')` return an empty string instead `None` if the ID does not exist?

Comment: the statement is returning None when using ''

Comment: @efultz Maybe you have employees where the value of `externalEmployeeId` is explicitly `None`. The second argument to `get()` is only returned when the dictionary key is missing.

Comment: I found why my code is not working - just not how to fix it - turns out the field has some entries whose value is None so that is what is returned - going to have to switch to regular for-loop so I can account for that

Comment: That is exactly what I have found - I am switching to a fatter for-loop so I may handle that condition

Comment: I've updated my answer with a cleaner code to handle explicitly `None` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if the result is `None` it will put an empty string :

```
EmployeeIDs = [Employee.get('externalEmployeeId', '').lower() if Employee.get('externalEmployeeId', '') is not None else "" for Employee in activeEmployees]
```

Answer (score 2):

`''` is an empty string, not `None`, and an empty string still has the `lower()` method that you can call. Use the `or` operator to default `None` entries to `''` instead:

```
EmployeeIDs = [(Employee.get('externalEmployeeId') or '').lower() for Employee in activeEmployees]
```

would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom function to use in the list comprehension:

```
def get_lowercase_external_id(e):
    try:
        return e.get('externalEmployeeId', '').lower()
    except AttributeError:  # 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
        return None

EmployeeIDs = [get_lowercase_external_id(Employee) for Employee in activeEmployees]
```

If you want to want to remove all `None`IDs, use a generator function instead (which is more efficient than a for-loop appending to a list):

```
def get_lowercase_external_ids(es):
    for e in es:
        try:
            yield e.get('externalEmployeeId', '').lower()
        except AttributeError:
            continue

EmployeeIDs = list(get_lowercase_external_ids(activeEmployees))
```